# Javascript obtain pixel color from leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, wms

I Have a leaflet map with some wms layers obtained via request to geoserver, the result is the map with the points added.

I want to detect the pixel color where the cursor is in this map to change the cursor icon, I want to do this because the layers are an image and cannot know nothing if I don't make a getFeatureInfo request to the geoserver.

```
var container = map.getContainer();
map.whenReady(function() {
    container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        // Establecer el tamaño del canvas para que sea igual que el contenedor
        canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;

        // Obtener el contexto de dibujo del canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
        // Obtener los valores RGB del píxel en la posición (100, 200)
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x - 5, y -5, 11, 11);
        var pixelData = imageData.data; // pixelData es un arreglo de 4 valores (R, G, B, alpha)
        console.log(pixelData);
        var red = pixelData[0];
        var green = pixelData[1];
        var blue = pixelData[2];

        // Convertir los valores RGB a una cadena hexadecimal
        var hex = '#' + red.toString(16) + green.toString(16) + blue.toString(16);
        console.log('El color del píxel es ' + hex);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
        console.log('Error al cargar el mapa');
        };
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        console.log(img.src);
    });
});
```

Here this seems to be creating a white canvas, because this works but every log is returning me 000, the problem seems to not creating an img with what the user can see in the map

I was about to give up, but with a color picker addon from google Chrome I can see the colors of the map without problem, so I don't understand why I can't make it here.

Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, you're not referring to the image being used by Leaflet, at all. You're creating an empty image and canvas, then copy the canvas to the image, then the empty image to the canvas. Start by getting a reference to the `L.Layer` which is loading the WMS.